# bug in cs50 caesor, one letter ciphering wrongly

Tags: c, cs50

upon entering

`./caesar 65` and
`plaintext: barfoo` the letter "f" does not change properly, it becomes "Y" instead of "s".

This is the code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(int argc, string argv[]) //argc(argument count) counts stores how many WORDS typed, argv (argument vector) array of the words typed at the prompt
{
  if (argv[1] == NULL)
  {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
    return 1;
  }
  if (argc != 2){
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
    return 1;
  }
  //if key val is entered correctly
  int key;
  for(int i=0; i<strlen(argv[1]); i++)
  {
    if (isdigit(argv[1][i])) //check whether each digit of input is 0-9
    {
      key = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);//key value is stored > shorturl.at/bdmPS
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
      return 1;
    }
  }
   string input = get_string("plaintext:  ");
   printf("ciphertext: ");
 
   if (key > 26)
   {
     key = key % 26;
   }
   int new_pos;
   for (int i=0; i < strlen(input); i++)
   {
       int i_int = (int) input[i]; //convert each character to ascii num
       if (i_int >= 65 && i_int <= 90)// if it is uppercase
       {
          if ((key + i_int) > 90)
          {
            key = key - 26;
            new_pos = i_int + key;
          }
 
          else
          {
            new_pos = i_int + key;
          }
          char letter = (char) new_pos; //convert the new ascii position back to char
          printf("%c", letter);//no newline
       }
       else if(i_int >= 97 && i_int <= 122) //if lowercase
       {
          if ((key + i_int) > 122)
          {
            key = key - 26;
            new_pos = i_int + key;
          }
          else
          {
            new_pos = i_int + key;
          }
          char letter = (char) new_pos; //convert the new ascii position back to char
          printf("%c", letter);//no newline
       }
       else //if it is not an alphabet
       {
          printf("%c", i_int); //convert back to char
       }
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Becasue your code alters the key (instead of the encoded letter) when the alphabet wraps. Change both lines of `key = key - 26;` to `i_int = i_int - 26;`

Comment: @WeatherVane 13 + 102(ascii of "f") does not make the following condition true 
` if ((key + i_int) > 122)` on line 60. So there should not be a difference between your code and mine.

Your reply does work however.

Comment: You had already changed the `key` by then. You had subtracted `26` from it so it was  `-13` and then `'f' - 13` is `'Y'`, a smaller ASCII value which isn't > 122.

Comment: @WeatherVane, i think  i should have included the declaration of 'key' for every loop , instead of at the start, that way it would not have been -13. Thank you :)

Comment: I think that would be confusing. What you should have done is to calculate the cipher, and *then* adjust it if out-of-range. `new_pos = i_int + key; if(new_pos > 'Z') new_pos -= 26;` . I didn't mention before: don't use magic numbers: use the actual letters.